# How to get Intellisense to only show the Properties or only the Events etc

Tags: visual-studio-2010, visual-studio-2008, intellisense

I'm sure I'm not the only one who finds it a bit annoying when scanning say Events in Intellisense and having to wade thru all the Properties etc as well. Is there a way/plugin or something to allow the selection of only Events, only Properties etc?

That would really be a big plus!

Comment: which platform/tool etc?

Comment: I assume he uses Visual Studio, since Intellisense is the name Microsoft uses for code completion?

Answer (score 2):

I'm pretty sure I've seen resharper or coderush have these options. Can't remember which - sorry.

I also found this article ['Customizing Intellisense](http://weblogs.foxite.com/andykramek/archive/2005/04/03/334.aspx)', which shows you how to do it in code.

Comment: Thx. A simpler solution would be better, hopefully in CodeRush. Maybe someone else knows.