# How to filter by type in IntelliSense?

Tags: c#, .net, visual-studio-2010, intellisense

I want to see only the events for a given object. But when I use IntelliSense shows all members.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think it's not possible out of the box for c# code, see [msdn](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/forums/en-US/csharpide/thread/0da4fe7f-acfd-4430-8c24-c82143da8d24/) and [stackoverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1524650/how-to-get-intellisense-to-only-show-the-properties-or-only-the-events-etc). 
For some obscure reason filtering *does* work in the xaml Editor.

With Resharper you [have the filter functionality though](https://www.jetbrains.com/resharper/help/Using_Filters_in_Code_Completion.html).

Comment: Where is this feature in Resharper? I can't find it.

Comment: There is none in ReSharper, at least nothing even close to Visual Assist X's.

Answer (score 14):

One of the features of a Visual Studio addin, called Visual Assist X, is the [enhanced IntelliSense](http://www.wholetomato.com/features/feature-coding-assistance.asp), which allows you to filter by events, properties, methods, etc:

[image: Visual Assist X]

It's not exactly what you asked, but it's pretty close.

Comment: i have visual studio 2013, resharper and visual assist. i dont know why but this visual assist unique and practical feature are missing on my setup.

Comment: In VA-X it is called "Enhanced Listboxes" and it is located under the "Listboxes" section (the first checkbox of "Listboxes" tab - in my setup at least). Very helpfull option. (I wonder why this is disabled by default...)

Answer (score 2):

In Visual Studio 2017 check this option:

```
Tools -> Options -> Text Editor -> C# -> IntelliSense -> Show completion item filters.
```

You may use icons or shortcut keys to filter particular categories. Unfortunately, I found this option only in C# and Basic. I expect it in XAML.

Answer (score 0):

IIRC, ReSharper supports this.

Comment: @Brettetete yes it does: https://www.jetbrains.com/resharper/help/Using_Filters_in_Code_Completion.html

Answer (score 0):

The new version of Visual Studio (Today it's named "Visual Studio 15 Preview 3", it should be renamed as VS 2016 or VS 2017 later...) natively support this feature. It was presented in Build 2016, take a look at this video of the presentation in the exactly time that they talked about it:
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=RNpFHbEaNpU#t=2644

Answer (score 0):

The latest version of visual studio has buttons in intellisense widnow, to filter based on property, event or method. Please see the screenshot below:

[image: Intellisense buttons]

Comment: where do you go to enable that?

Comment: @AC25, I didn't change anything.  It's out of the box. Visual Studio 2019 has even more options to filter on.